# IIS7 Block request to asp.net app using external IP

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have a asp.net app (IIS7), and I want block access to it using external server IP. I only want to allow access using my domain.

For example, my domain is domain.com and IP 161.0.0.1 and I want to block the access to http://161.0.0.1/webapp/

I prefer do it using web.config

Thx in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IIS you configure exactly what IP / DNS name combination you want the site to respond to.  You can easily force it to only respond on a particular IP.

For IIS 7:

1. Open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
2. Expand Sites and right click on your website.
3. Click on Edit Bindings.
4. Edit the existing entry and set the IP address to 161.0.0.1.  Also set the domain name to domain.com.
5. Click OK, the Click Close.

Now your site wil only respond to that particular domain name and won't respond via IP address only.

If your site uses an SSL certificate then see the following question which talks about how to configure IIS to force the hostname to be used:

https://serverfault.com/questions/96810/iis7-cant-set-host-name-on-site-with-ssl-cert-and-port-443
which links to:
http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html

This link is even better for doing it entirely through the UI: http://blog.armgasys.com/?p=80

Comment: That's not what he is asking for.  If the server only has one IP and one DNS hostname pointing to that IP, he wants the server to respond when the DNS hostname is requested but NOT when the IP is requested.

Comment: @pseudocoder: In that case, set the domain name along with the IP.  IIS won't allow direct IP address requests in that case.  Slight edit to make this clear.

Comment: That is also true and is mentioned in my most recent post, but doesn't work for HTTPS.  That is why I included the HttpModule example.

Comment: @pseudocoder: Actually, it does work for HTTPS, but you can't set it through the UI.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/96810/iis7-cant-set-host-name-on-site-with-ssl-cert-and-port-443

Comment: +1 for HTTPS bindings solution - why didn't you include that in your original answer?

Comment: @pseudocoder:  He didn't list SSL as a requirement, so I didn't think it was necessary.  However, after going back and forth with you it's apparent future readers ought to know. ;)

Answer (score 2):

OK so if you want the Site to be accessible via DNS name but not via IP, the only way to distinguish that is to examine the requested host name in the header.  There are two ways to do that I know of:

1) Configure Bindings dialog in IIS Manager.  This is the easiest to set up but doesn't work for HTTPS.  Just put www.domain.com into the hostname field and requests to the IP will be rejected.  For HTTPS if your security certificate is for a specific hostname, the user will get a security warning if they try to connect via IP, but typically they can override the warning (depending on browser settings).

**Edit:** Chris Lively has linked to a way to make this method work for HTTPS bindings as well, see his answer for more information.

2) Alternately you can examine the header in code.  Here is an example of an `IHttpModule` which accomplishes what you want.  It is also a drop-in solution that is configured in web.config.

Code:

```
Public Class HostNameCheck
    Implements IHttpModule

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Dispose
    End Sub

    Public Sub Init(context As System.Web.HttpApplication) Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Init
        AddHandler context.BeginRequest, AddressOf context_BeginRequest
    End Sub

    Private Sub context_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim objApp As HttpApplication = DirectCast(sender, HttpApplication)

        If objApp.Request.Url.Host <> ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AcceptedHostName") Then
            objApp.Response.Clear()
            objApp.Response.StatusCode = 403
            objApp.Response.SubStatusCode = 6
            objApp.Response.Flush()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="AcceptedHostName" value="www.domain.com"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="HostNameCheck" type="HostNameCheck"/>
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: +1 for the IHttpModule way of doing things. If the programmer doesn't have access to IIS manager then this might be their last option.